# To read desired values from file using linux system commands (grep,awk,sed)

Tags: linux, awk, sed, command-line, grep

I have file test.txt  contains some variables assigned to some value, i need to read all defined variables for example color = 0;. Basically i am trying to read here is the values which are previous line of parameters()->getParm(" ");

can you please help me out how i can read these values. Also mentioned my expected result.

```
cat test.txt

   color = 0;
   parameters()->getParm(&color, "-color");
   
   width = 16;
   parameters()->getParm(&width, "-width");

   size = 0;
   parameters()->getParm(&size, "-size");

   species = "Taxon";      
   parameters()->getParm(&species, "-species");

   fly = 100;
   parameters()->getParm(&fly, "-fly");

   swim = 25;
   parameters()->getParm(&swim, "-swim");
```

```
 

    expected result:
     color = 0;
     width = 16;
     size = 0;
     species = "Taxon";
     fly = 100;
     swim = 25;
```

Comment: Please do add your efforts/tried code in your question, to avoid "close votes" on your question(which is highly encouraged on SO), thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: `can you please help me` Use `awk`, it looks like a short script.  [here is sed introduction](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html), but [here is for awk](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-4) and awk has also [a tutorial on tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/index.htm). `grep` is for filtering _lines_ - lines in this case wont help you, you want to extract data from lines.

Comment: Your example is probably too trivial; `grep -vF 'parameters()->getParm'` would already do roughly what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it following way using GNU `AWK`, let `file.txt` content be

```
   color = 0;
   parameters()->getParm(&color, "-color");
   
   width = 16;
   parameters()->getParm(&width, "-width");

   size = 0;
   parameters()->getParm(&size, "-size");

   species = "Taxon";      
   parameters()->getParm(&species, "-species");

   fly = 100;
   parameters()->getParm(&fly, "-fly");

   swim = 25;
   parameters()->getParm(&swim, "-swim");
```

then

```
awk '/parameters()/{print line}{line=$0}' file.txt
```

output

```
   color = 0;
   width = 16;
   size = 0;
   species = "Taxon";      
   fly = 100;
   swim = 25;
```

Explanation: We need to store previous line so we can `print` it when we find line meeting condition. I use variable name `line` for storing it, I instructed `awk` that for each line: if it does contain `parameters()` `print` previous line (stored in variable `line`), always store current line as `line`. Beware that this solution assumes that line with `parameters()` will never be first line and relevant line is always immediately before line with `parameters()`.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*